# Calculus textbook question!!??

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I am thinking of buying calculus by James Stewart and was wondering if it covers cal 1 2 and 3? If so is there anything else I should get to go with it? If not is there recommendations on what else I should get to cover higher level calculus? I am teaching myself and plan on getting into spivak eventually but for now start with the basics.

Comment: What are "cal 1 2 and 3"?  Presumably, this means the "standard" three semester of undergraduate calculus courses in the US?  If so, I would suggest that you get a syllabus for such a sequence of classes, then compare the syllabus to the table of contents.  Alternatively, ask someone who is teaching that sequence of courses what book or books they might recommend.

Comment: Theoretically, Spivak doesn't require you to already know calculus. In practice, if you don't know any calculus at all then you don't have enough mathematical maturity to understand it. But certainly the calculus 3 is completely irrelevant to Spivak's calculus, and I took a course that used Spivak as my very first math course in college, after doing only calculus 1 in high school.

Comment: Granted, I had been exposed to more advanced math that I wasn't taught because I read random advanced textbooks as a child because I was obsessed with math and there was no one to teach me. Most of it I didn't understand, but I had definitely covered calculus 2. I never took calculus 2 in college, took a proficiency test to get credit for it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The question "What calc textbook should I use?" must have been answered many many times already. Just search for similar question on the search bar.

Comment: My opinions: for first-time learning Calculus you should get Thomas Calculus or Lang Calculus.Thomas is better and more beautiful than Larson and Stewart. Leithold Calculus is a little more rigorous than Thomas but there are too many examples and that drags the book down. Spivak calculus is good but over-rated. Apostol Calculus is the most rigorous but it is poorly explained and it's hard to follow his steps.

Comment: @Matt Samuel: "*I never took calculus 2 in college, took a proficiency test to get credit for it.*" --- FYI, despite having taught at least 30 calculus courses, I've never taken anything remotely equivalent to any of the courses calculus 1, calculus 2, or calculus 3 (or Spivak calculus, or Apostol calculus, etc.), either in high school or in college (or elsewhere, if there's a possibility I'm overlooking, such as math camps, summer programs, or some such), by doing what you did, although a bit more extreme.

Answer (score 1):

here is a great resource for deciding what math textbooks to purchase.

> https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are several versions of Stewart. The largest version is indeed meant as a textbook that can be taken through a full three-semester calculus sequence, and is well suited to the needs of a normal student.

To make sure you're getting that version instead of one of the shorter and lighter versions that cover less material, check the table of contents and make sure that the topics run all the way from limits in chapter 1 to the likes of surface integrals in chapter ~14 (I don't have a copy lying around, and it's been a while).

If you're interested in challenging yourself some, Stewart has sets of "Problems Plus" between some of the chapters, which call for additional clever thought beyond the routine algorithms needed for the text's homework exercises.

If you intend to take a formal course, just get whatever the textbook for that course is.

Comment: No intent on taking the formal class for now. I am in school for nursing but I love math and science so I plan on teaching myself a lot of math and physics just because I like it and I want to take it upon myself to see if it would be worth going back later to take the classes when I can do it more as a hobby.